# Add splashscreen before video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have:

- `splash.png` having the same size as video resolution
- `video.mp4` in 60 fps already encoded via `-vcodec h264 -crf 23 -acodec copy`

I want to prepend (not overlay) video `video.mp4` with splashscreen `splash.png` for 5 seconds.

If possible, I'd like to keep video without reencoding as otherwice additional artefacts may appear. Or maybe it's possible to reencode with the same codec without quality loss?

What `ffmpeg` command I should use to achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481882/adding-splash-screen-to-start-of-video-using-ffmpeg seems to have an answer